# Show play button when hoving over an album

Tags: javascript, spotify, playback

There are many Spotify apps including Pitchfork and Rolling Stone which show a play button in the lower left corner when hovering over an album cover. Here's an [example](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s8/sh/b2018598-034c-4397-9353-ffcf8d684914/7bc02c7e8c8e5f84d5b88996e4dbdf53/res/3bdf8a18-ab82-4d5d-8170-a3a853e474cf/skitch.png). Does the Spotify API support this natively? What is the best way to code this? Thanks.

Comment: The example link doesn't work. Access denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the standard `Player` view. Create it with a track and album URI and insert it into your DOM as you would any other UI element in JavaScript.

Documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/ca28d10757/).

There's an example of how to use it in the Spotify tutorial app, available [here](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial) on GitHub, in the "Play a single track" example. If you modify that example to use an album instead of a single track playlist, you'll have what you need.